# Good way to offer both LWCs and a REST API in the same code?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, rest-api, lightning-web-components, restresource, aura-enabled

We are building a product that will make use of multiple Lightning Web Components (LWCs), and some of those will make use of `@AuraEnabled` Apex methods. We also plan to provide an API that non-LWC UI can access. (In the past, we have provided such APIs by using `@RestResource` Apex classes receiving and sending JSON.)

Our present idea is to go ahead and build the `@AuraEnabled` Apex code methods/classes first, and then later wrap them in a single `@RestResource` Apex class that dispatches the requests according to the URL pattern to the relevant `@AuraEnabled` methods/classes. (I assume in this case the `@AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)` annotation will be ignored.)

Has anyone done this? Pros/cons?

Comment: From a separation of concerns perspective it is better to provide the business logic in one class and to provide appropriate (at)AuraEnabled and (at)RestResource facades in two separate classes that leverage the business logic class.

Comment: Yep @PhilW, Yeah fair point. Perhaps the separation should be at the method level e.g. the `@AuraEnabled` method calls a plain method (also called by the `@RestResource` code), but then that is close to what I am already proposing. The only extra concern for the `@AuraEnabled` case is the `@AuraEnabled` annotation...

Comment: Well, it rather depends on whether the business logic is 1:1 with any one of the methods exposed to the "APIs". I said "facade" because these frequently provide a way to view and interact with the business logic and related data is subtly different ways. One of the benefits of such an approach is allowing you to refactor the behind-the-scenes code without impacting any of your APIs (you can also think of these as the traditional layers in an application - front end<->API<->business logic<->persistence). The API layer might also encapsulate more of the security concerns too.

Comment: Hi @PhilW, thanks for your attention here! If a layer does something significant then +1; I'm allergic to thin layers that just cause method interfaces to be duplicated e.g. the ugly controller/helper setup in Aura.

Comment: The point I mentioned about security concerns - in cases where security can be considered at the API level, perhaps applying an "all or nothing" security approach (if you have all permissions, call the logic otherwise don't call it and return an error), the business logic can be considered a "utility" and not apply CRUD/FLS or other checks of its own. Each "entry point" (REST and LWC/Aura here) can apply the checks relevant to their context of use. For example, perhaps the logic creates new objects that are returned through REST but not to the LWC. REST checks perms, but LWC doesn't need to.

Comment: (Clearly, whatever you do needs to pass security review and there needs to be a good reason to do what you do, but hopefully you get my drift)

Comment: @PhilW, In this case, I don't think we would want separate access rights for the two access mechanisms, but you are right that security needs to be factored into the approach (as always).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Initial coding of the [KISS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle) solution:

```
global class Aura {

    // Call this from the REST API
    public static Object execute(String operation, String requestJson) {
        switch on operation {
            when 'op1' {
                return op1((Op1Params) JSON.deserialize(requestJson, Op1Params.class));
            }
            when 'op2' {
                return op2((Op2Params) JSON.deserialize(requestJson, Op2Params.class));
            }
            ...
        }
    }

    // Method used by LWC
    @AuraEnabled
    global static Result__c op1(Op1Params params) {
        ...
    }

    // Method used by LWC
    @AuraEnabled
    global static Result__c op2(Op2Params params) {
        ...
    }

    ...
}
```

and:

```
@RestResource(urlMapping = '/xyz/...')
global inherited sharing class Rest {

    ....

    @HttpPost
    global static void doPost() {

        Savepoint sp = Database.setSavepoint();
        try {
            dispatch(RestContext.request, RestContext.response);
        } catch (AuraHandledException e) {
            res.responseBody = Blob.valueOf(e.getMessage());
            res.statusCode = BAD_REQUEST;
            Database.rollback(sp);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            res.responseBody = Blob.valueOf(sanitizedMessage(e));
            res.statusCode = INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR;
            Database.rollback(sp);
        }
    }

    private static void dispatch(RestRequest req, RestResponse res) {

        String[] parts = req.requestURI.split('\\/');
        String operation = parts.size() > 1 ? parts[1] : null;
        String requestJson = req.requestBody.toString();

        Object result = Aura.execute(operation, requestJson);

        res.responseBody = toJsonBlob(result);
        res.statusCode = OK;
    }
}
```

Comment: It is the first time I see functions like Aura.execute and toJsonBlob, where can I find them?

Comment: Hi @GabrielSerranoSalas, Those are just locally created small methods.

Comment: Aura.execute as well? I have seen Aura.redirect in the past, although never documented anywhere. Just though Aura.execute could be similar